# Simple Makefile not taking include path

Tags: makefile

following is my makefile. but It is not taking include path during build.

```
SHELL   = /bin/sh
CC      = g++ 
FLAGS   = 
CFLAGS  = -fPIC 
TARGET  = my_bridge.so
INC=-I/my_custom_path/include/ -I/my_custom_path/include/linux

SOURCES = $(shell echo *.cpp)
HEADERS = $(shell echo *.h)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)
```

When I build i get following line

```
g++    -c -o my_bridge.o my_bridge.cpp
```

Comment: Please make sure, that line starting from `$(CC)` is indented with tab, not spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)` rule tells make how to generate `my_bridge.so` out of `my_bridge.o`, but you haven't given a rule that explains how to make `my_bridge.o` in the first place. `make` relies thus on its implicit rules for that, which gives you the command that you see. You can either define your own rule to compile `.cpp` files, e.g.

```
%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(INC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

or put your include directive in `$(CXXFLAGS)`, which is used by `make`'s default rule (see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)